# How to change Appearance mode on iOS programmatically?

Tags: react-native

On my react-native app I implemented dark mode, but this only is managed locally on my app using redux. On my iOS Splashscreen I implemented dark mode too.

The problem is, when **I switch to dark mode locally**(redux), the **design on my app changes**, everything is ok, but **not the Splashscreen**. I realized that **only when I change the Appearance settings** (Settings -> Developer -> Dark Appearance) to dark Mode, **Splashscreen mode changes too**.

I know that I can base it on user preferences to change to dark or light mode the app, but I need to control this locally and the dark mode apply on my app and Splashscreen also. Is this possible?

So, I guess, I need to change somehow the "Dark Appearance" programmatically. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`react-native-appearance-control`](https://github.com/72days/react-native-appearance-control). Combine this with the `Appearance` API in `react-native`, and you can implement a dark mode toggle that the user can interact with.

See a similar question here which might help to guide you - [Change colors of the whole app in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74598288/change-colors-of-the-whole-app-in-react-native)